# AIR Mobile - Textfield missing blue triangle cursor

Tags: android, air, textfield

Other android applications have a blue cursor that looks like a triangle with a rectangle at its base. This cursor lets you easily move the caret on the textfield. It seems like a default textfield behavior but my basic application for mobile does not have this cursor.

I have checked all of the methods and properties on a textfield and haven't found anything to turn this cursor on. Anyone know what I should be looking for?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Native Text Input with StageText instead.
This would help:
http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/09/native-text-input-with-stagetext.html